# How to extract data between yesterday and today?

Tags: sql-server, select, datetime

I have a column called `createdate` of `datetime` datatype. I want to extract data between today and yesterday.

```
select * from table1(nolock) where createdate ='2018-06-01' --not getting any output
```

I want something like this:

```
select * from table1(nolock) where createdate between '2018-06-01' and '2018-06-02'
```

Rather than hard coding the date, I need between `dateadd(d,-1,getdate()) and getdate()`, but `getdate()` gives current timestamp. How can I search for the whole day like `2018-06-02` rather than `2018-06-02 02:12:13.423`?

Comment: As a side note, please don't use `nolock` hint unless there's a good reason for it - and you are well aware of its [side effects](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always find today (with no time) using `SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE());`.

So to find all of the data for yesterday, you say:

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();

SELECT ...
WHERE createDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today)
  AND createDate <  @today;
```

For today, it's a simple change:

```
WHERE createDate >= @today
  AND createDate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @today);
```

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) - please edit to improve:</sub>*

Your condition `dateadd(d,-1,getdate()) and getdate()` is almost right.

You need for the yesterday value to get rid of time like:

```
dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-1,0)
```

So your condition will look like this:

```
where createDate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)  
  and createDate  < getdate()
```

If you only want things from yesterday, it should be:

```
WHERE     (txtDateTime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) AND (txtDateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to extract all the records between yesterday and today by selecting only DATE from datetime timestamp. here i wanted to get date in japan time zone[JST].

```
select * from [Table] where DATE(timestamp) between CAST( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tokyo' -1 AS Date ) and CAST( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tokyo' AS Date ) ;
```

Comment: `'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name`, says SQL Server.